# Same data is repeating in sections in UITableView and UICollectionView in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am new in swift working on an app, where I am binding data in a collectionView which is inside UITableView,
I am sending data (which are Images) in UICollectionView as an multidimensional array like this

```
[[<UIImage: 0x600000292610>, {1280, 720}, <UIImage: 0x600000292bb0>, {1000, 563}, <UIImage: 0x600000292c50>, {2048, 1200}, <UIImage: 0x6000002926b0>, {1080, 675}, <UIImage: 0x600000292c00>, {1156, 577}, <UIImage: 0x60800028e650>, {322, 156}], [<UIImage: 0x60800028e290>, {1600, 840}, <UIImage: 0x60800028de30>, {1640, 878}, <UIImage: 0x600000294e10>, {322, 156}, <UIImage: 0x600000294d70>, {1917, 1080}, <UIImage: 0x600000295310>, {1311, 737}, <UIImage: 0x60800028dac0>, {258, 195}], [<UIImage: 0x600000295720>, {1601, 1281}, <UIImage: 0x600000295630>, {1600, 1341}, <UIImage: 0x60800028f500>, {1200, 919}, <UIImage: 0x600000296e90>, {4088, 2921}], [<UIImage: 0x608000290ae0>, {1600, 584}, <UIImage: 0x600000297160>, {1400, 1050}, <UIImage: 0x600000296b70>, {717, 476}, <UIImage: 0x608000290e50>, {2280, 1060}, <UIImage: 0x600000297390>, {1068, 427}, <UIImage: 0x608000291260>, {3200, 1600}, <UIImage: 0x608000290e00>, {258, 195}], [<UIImage: 0x608000291490>, {1300, 630}, <UIImage: 0x6080002914e0>, {512, 366}, <UIImage: 0x608000290bd0>, {1200, 628}], [<UIImage: 0x600000297b60>, {1200, 628}, <UIImage: 0x6000002972f0>, {1536, 1024}, <UIImage: 0x608000291b70>, {1540, 705}, <UIImage: 0x6000002985b0>, {1200, 676}, <UIImage: 0x60800009c4d0>, {443, 377}]]
```

My issue is i am seeing sections 0,1,2 were being created uniquely but then section 3 was being generated the same as section 0,

Here is my code in collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfItemsInSection ******",self.imageArray[section].count,"********")
         return self.imageArray[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell: CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        {
           // if(imageArray[indexPath.section].count>0){
                print("---> ",indexPath.section," --- item ->",indexPath.row)
                cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            //}
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        print("numberOfSections ******",self.imageArray.count,"********")
        return self.imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        let size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 300)
        return size
    }
```

This is my tableView Controller

```
extension CompanyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if self.sectionHeaderName.count>0 {
            print("*******",self.sectionHeaderName[section],"*******")
            return self.sectionHeaderName[section]
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    }

    //NUMBER OF SECTION WE WANT IN A TABLE
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sectionHeaderName.count
    }
    /*NUMNBER OF ROWS IN A SECTION*/
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        {

            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I am struggling here since 2 days but couldn't find any solution.
Any Help would be appreciated

TIA

Comment: you should not use `indexPath.row` in `UICollectionView`, use `indexPath.item` instead. hopefully this will solve your issue

Comment: Hi I have changed to this `cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]` but it is showing me the same result.

and `return self.imageArray[section].count`

Answer (score 2):

You should **set data source or delegate** in TableViewCell **willDisplay**.

```swift
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate, forRow row: Int) {
    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

```swift
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? TableViewCell else { return }

    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Hi it started throwing error after adding this code

Comment: What kind of error? By the way, my answer just an example. You should not copy&paste directly.

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`
i have changed a bit and tried, and I checked  identifier `cell` is already defined

Comment: You should register your custom collection view cell like this `collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
`

Comment: I have already defined cell in storyboard, is it required to define programatically. 
because when I define using this line it again throwing error while running

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the answer after scratching head for 3 days

I had to pass my data from TableView Extension in cellForRowAt function like this

```
cell.cellData = self.imageArray[indexPath.section]
return cell
```

And in TableViewCell where I defined my CollectionView I have declared the variable

```
 var cellData = [UIImage]()
```

and Used the same variable to get the Images in all collection view functions

In `CellForItemAt` Need to  get data from array like below and used row instead of items and section because when scrolling the tableView up and down image may get shuffle or wrongly displayed in cell, so by using `indexPath.row` it will prevent shuffling of Images.

```
cell?.imageView.image = cellData[indexPath.row]
```

One more thing which I need to add is

```
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```

because TableView was taking reference fo my first array index instead of what I am passing.

Thanks